# Getting error while uploading data to elastic search

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

**Issue:**

When I send the data using the below curl command to elastic search im getting the below error

Command :
I created the below template using the curl command and it worked fine

> curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/_template/cn_health_monitoring -d '{"template":"cn_health_monitoring","settings":{"index.refresh_interval":"5s"},"mappings":{"*default*":{"_all":{"enabled":true},"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"string"},"appliance_id_string":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mother_board_serial_number":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mother_board_name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}}'

But

When I send the data using the below command I get the error 500 or 400

> curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_bulk -d '{"index":{"_index":"cn_health_monitoring","_type":"ipfix"}} \n
>       {"@timestamp":"2015-07-18 21:39:10","appliance_id_string":" 32444335-3732-4A31-5143-A0B3CC82A9B1""mother_board_serial_number":" 5CD2271JQC","mother_board_name":" HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC"}'

Error:

```
{
    "error": "ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]",
    "status": 500
}
```

and

```
{
    "took": 219,
    "errors": true,
    "items": [
        {
            "create": {
                "_index": "cn_health_monitoring",
                "_type": "ipfix",
                "_id": "ghfPSLv1Tayw03jTr0Zi6Q",
                "status": 400,
                "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You have missing comma before the mother_board_serial_number

Then, you can do this using file (maybe there are other ways, but this seems to work)

```
eran@eran-laptop:~$ cat r
{"index":{"_index":"cn_health_monitoring","_type":"ipfix"}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-07-18 21:39:10","appliance_id_string":" 32444335-3732-4A31-5143-A0B3CC82A9B1","mother_board_serial_number":" 5CD2271JQC","mother_board_name":" HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC"}

eran@eran-laptop:~$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @r 
{"took":2,"errors":false,"items":[{"create":{"_index":"cn_health_monitoring","_type":"ipfix","_id":"AU6lweKRmOtv0CHjm9cD","_version":1,"status":201}}]}
```

Comment: I removed the comma,sorry didn't update it in the question,but it still gave me an error

Comment: did you try with the file? You need to use the --data-binary according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html